# flutter gridview infinite both axis

Tags: flutter, gridview, scroll

my app needs to display a large number of cells(>200) and I can easily scroll verically with the code below but I need to scroll gridview  horizontally also. the cells need to be fixed width and not scale to fit as happens with the crossAxisCount . requirement has need for at least 30 columns of fixed width and at least 30 rows

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'test',
  home: Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 5,
          ) ,
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Container(
                color: _randomColor(index),
                height: 200.0
            );
          }),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Grid will always have at least one axis as set length, both axes can't be infinite.

As a solution could use two SingleChildScrollView, one vertical and one horizontal, and wrap whatever child (in my example 15 rows x 15 columns) with it:

```
  SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Row(
        children: List.generate(
          15,
          (index) => Column(
              children: List.generate(
                  15,
                  (index) => Container(
                      width: 200,
                      height: 200,
                      color: Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0)))),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: great answer thanks. surprised the gridview has this restriction but this solution should do

Comment: Any thoughts on how this can be made lazy (using ListView.builder or gridview.builder)? As for large elements it will slow down the ui.